# How to print the entire row for particular time interval using python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to get the starttime and endtime from user.Then i need to print the entire row of starttime to end time.

Below is the data available in 'xsss.csv’ file

aaaaa   lshds   aaaaa   aaaaa   5:18    ss

dslkd   lsh2ds  dslkd   dslkd   5:19    dd

lshds   lshds   lshds   lshds   5:20    dd

aaaaa   aaaaa   aaaaa   aaaaa   5:21    dase

dslkd   dslkd   dslkd   dslkd   5:22    daew

lshds   lshds   lshds   lshds   5:23    sare

aaaas   aaaas   aaaas   aaaas   5:24    ddd

dslkd   dslkd   dslkd   dslkd   5:25    dss

d hdd   d hdd   d hdd   d hdd   5:26    dfsgdsg

ddddd   ddddd   ddddd   ddddd   5:26    dsdf

wswsx   wswsx   wswsx   wswsx   5:27    dw

swswq   swswq   swswq   swswq   5:28    ff

If starttime=5:18 and endtime= 5:20.Then output should print like below

aaaaa lshds aaaaa aaaaa 5:18 ss

dslkd lsh2ds dslkd dslkd 5:19 dd

lshds lshds lshds lshds 5:20 dd

The code snippet:

import os,csv,datetime

from datetime import datetime

starttime=datetime.strptime(raw_input('start time:' ),"%H:%M")

endtime=datetime.strptime(raw_input('end time:' ),"%H:%M")

print starttime

print type(starttime)

with open('csvv.csv') as d:

```
 line =d.readlines()

 print "ell"

 for line in d:

     print  "jjj"    

     if row == starttime and endtime:

         print row
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: If starttime=5:18 and endtime= 5:20.Expected output is it should print the entire line which is having time 5:18,5:19 and 5:20

Comment: Thanks .I got the answer